# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libtorrent'

Tags: python, libtorrent

I tried to run this below code in google colabratory:

```
!apt install python3-libtorrent

import libtorrent as lt
```

I was able to `install python3-libtorrent`. But am unable to import libtorrent. But the import attempt above gave a

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'libtorrent'
```

Answer (score 31):

Paste these two lines before the first line in the code.

```
!python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
!python -m pip install lbry-libtorrent
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It really works. I am in your debt. Again thank you so much. This will help a lot of people.

Comment: Could you provide an explanation for why adding those extra lines?

Answer (score 3):

```
!python -m pip install lbry-libtorrent
!apt install python3-libtorrent
 
import libtorrent as lt
 
ses = lt.session()
ses.listen_on(6881, 6891)
downloads = []
```

No need ;) !python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

Comment: Excluding the line```!apt install python3-libtorrent```, the rest would get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
!python -m pip install lbry-libtorrent
```